# Swift AVFoundation

Tags: swift, avfoundation

This is actually two problems
they are marked with //*****************************
I put the entire class in this post,

**the first is**

```
//====================================
//====================================
    @IBAction func btnMakeReport(_ sender: Any) {

        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        //****************    self is erroring... getting...
        // /Users/vyoumans/Documents/vyDEVELOPMENT/iOS/TESTS/camtest11/camtest11/VCCam02a.swift:104:61: Argument type 'VCCam02a' does not conform to expected type 'AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate'

        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
```

Could I get some sugestions on why self would not confirm to AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelagate.

**the second...** 
    //**************   image is error...  but I define image above.

I declare image at the begining of the class.  This error in //====================================
extension ViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate { 
at bottom of app

Thanks

//--------   begining of code . ------------

```
'
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

//====================================

class VCCam02a: UIViewController {
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentCamrera: AVCaptureDevice?

    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?

    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

//    var image: UIImage?
    var image: UIImage?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()


    }
//====================================
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

//====================================
//====================================
    func setupCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    }

//====================================
    func setupDevice() {
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)

        let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                backCamera = device
            } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
                frontCamera = device
            }
        }

        currentCamrera = backCamera
    }



//====================================
    func setupInputOutput() {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamrera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

//====================================
    func setupPreviewLayer() {
        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
    }

//====================================
    func startRunningCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
//====================================
//====================================
    @IBAction func btnMakeReport(_ sender: Any) {

        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
//****************    self is erroring... getting...
// /Users/vyoumans/Documents/vyDEVELOPMENT/iOS/TESTS/camtest11/camtest11/VCCam02a.swift:104:61: Argument type 'VCCam02a' does not conform to expected type 'AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate'

        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
        // performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto_Segue", sender: nil)
    }
//====================================
    @IBAction func btnCancel(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


//====================================
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showPhoto_Segue" {
            let VCPreviewViewController = segue.destination as! VCPreviewViewController
            VCPreviewViewController.image = self.image
        }
    }
//====================================
//====================================
//====================================
//====================================
//====================================
//====================================
//====================================
//====================================
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
//====================================
extension ViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {

   //**************   image is error...  but I define image above.
            ///Users/vyoumans/Documents/vyDEVELOPMENT/iOS/TESTS/camtest11/camtest11/VCCam02a.swift:143:13: Use of unresolved identifier 'image'

            image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto_Segue", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}


//====================================
//====================================
//====================================
//====================================
//====================================


'
```

Comment: This question is very hard to read.

Comment: You must be missing some essential delegate methods. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotocapturedelegate)

Comment: Also extension must be `extension VCCam02a: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` not `extension UIViewControler `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this line:

```
photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
```

Seems to be the problem. It sounds like you're getting a compiler error that self does not conform to the `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` protocol.

That's pretty self-explanatory. If your class conforms to the `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` protocol, you need to add that conformance to the class definition, or to an extension:

```
class VCCam02a: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate
```

You will then need to implement all the methods in that protocol needed to handle the type of capture you are doing. To Quote the docs:

> All methods in this protocol are optional at compile time, but at run
>   time your delegate object must respond to certain methods depending on
>   your photo settings:

(See the Apple docs on the protocol for more information.)

Comment: Glad I could help. You should read up on Swift protocols and protocol conformance. It's an important concept that's widely used in Swift iOS and MacOS development.